# How to test a Grails service that retrieves information from the HTTP session

Tags: grails, integration-testing, grails3

I am trying to write tests for a Grails web-plugin.  The plugin contains a service (UtilityService) which has a function called getSession() which returns the GrailsHttpSession.  Other services use that to read/write values in the session.  The code is working just fine, but when I try to write tests for any function that uses the returned session object, the tests fail.

My goal at this point is to simply write a test which proves that utilityService.getSession() is returning something.

I am currently working with Grails 3.2.7

**UtilityService:**

```
package psu.util

import grails.transaction.Transactional
import grails.core.GrailsApplication
import grails.util.Environment

import grails.core.*
import org.grails.web.util.WebUtils
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest

@Transactional
class UtilityService {
    GrailsApplication grailsApplication

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsHttpSession getSession(){
        return WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest()?.session
    }

}
```

**Test:**

```
package psu.util

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.integration.Integration
import grails.transaction.*
import spock.lang.*

@Integration
@Rollback
@TestFor(UtilityService)
class UtilityServiceIntegrationSpec extends Specification {

    def setup() {
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void "test getSession"() {
        expect:
        service.getSession()
    }
}
```

**Test Output:**

```
Condition not satisfied:

service.getSession()
|       |
|       null
psu.util.UtilityService@28eab745
```

**Questions:**
Is there something that I need to do to make the session available in the TEST environment?  Is it possible to do this in a Unit test, or does it have to be an Integration test?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but you don't need a transaction to get a session, you're opening a connection to the db and doing nothing with it for your `getSession()`

Comment: There is no good reason to have a service provide a `getSession` method that other services will call.  Any service can implement `grails.web.api.ServletAttributes` and then in that service code can simply refer to `session`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250539/grails-no-thread-bound-request-found has a good solution.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The easiest way is to mock getSession method and return session mock (or Grails GrailsMockHttpSession), its simple as that in Groovy:

```
@TestFor(SessionService)
class SessionMockSpec extends Specification {

    GrailsHttpSession session

    def setup() {
        session = Mock()
        service.metaClass.getSession = { session }
    }

    def 'should return session'() {
        expect:
            service.getSession()
    }
```

Comment: This is not a good answer.  The question includes "My goal at this point is to simply write a test which proves that utilityService.getSession() is returning something.".  The solution provided in this answer completely avoids calling the method being tested.  This test is only testing the test, not the code in the service.

Answer (score 2):

The project at https://github.com/jeffbrown/mikegostomskiplugin demonstrates one way to do it.

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mikegostomskiplugin/blob/5dcb2953f1dc8eb20deefb26cdfa54e6f77617e6/grails-app/services/psu/util/UtilityService.groovy

```
package psu.util

import grails.web.api.ServletAttributes

class UtilityService implements ServletAttributes {

    def getSomethingFromSession(String key) {
        session[key]
    }
}
```

https://github.com/jeffbrown/mikegostomskiplugin/blob/5dcb2953f1dc8eb20deefb26cdfa54e6f77617e6/src/test/groovy/psu/util/UtilityServiceSpec.groovy

```
package psu.util

import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.web.ControllerUnitTestMixin
import spock.lang.Specification

@TestFor(UtilityService)
@TestMixin(ControllerUnitTestMixin)
class UtilityServiceSpec extends Specification {

    void 'test interacting with session'() {
        when:
        session.'Some Session Key' = 'King Crimson Is Awesome'

        then:
        service.getSomethingFromSession('Some Session Key') == 'King Crimson Is Awesome'
    }
}
```

Comment: implements ServletAttributes does the trick to let services access the htto session

Comment: Right.  It is designed to do that.  This is how Controllers get access to the session.  At compile time we add the `ServletAttributes` to all controller classes and we publish the trait so you can use it in other classes as appropriate.