# Grails No thread-bound request found

Tags: http, grails

I am using a Grails service closure to perform a `async HTTP request` to another web application. Using `Grails 1.3.9`, I am very limited here.  The code runs inside a thread. It is called from a scheduled job and from several function calls. The error I get is below:

ERROR:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

CODE:

```
    Thread.start {

        def http = new HTTPBuilder(grailsApplication?.config?.smsConfig?.smsServiceAddress);

        try {
            http.request(POST) {

                body = bodyRequest;
                requestContentType = ContentType.JSON

                response.success = { resp ->
                    println "SUCCESS! ${resp.status}"

                    def user = RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getSession().user

                    if (user != null) {
                        if (termin) {
                            termin.withTransaction {

                                try {
                                    // do desired action

                                } catch (e) {
                                    println(e);
                                }

                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                response.failure = { resp ->
                    println "FAILURE request failed with status ${resp.status}, response body was [${resp.entity.content.text}]"
                    System.out << resp
                }
            }
        }
        //here error is caught
        catch (e) {
            log.error "Error: " + e;
        }
    }
```

I have tried adding this options to web.xml

```
    <listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
```

and also this to WebXmlConfig.groovy

```
    listener.add = true
listener.classNames = ["org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener"]
```

but both did not help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something that isn't well documented or can you send you spirals:

Try [this](https://github.com/vahidhedayati/grails-queuekit-plugin/blob/master/grails-app/services/org/grails/plugin/queuekit/reports/QueuekitBaseReportsService.groovy#L114-L122):

```
/*
* Fix for No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes
*/
def webRequest = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes()
if(!webRequest) {
    def servletContext  = ServletContextHolder.getServletContext()
    def applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext)
    webRequest =  grails.util.GrailsWebMockUtil.bindMockWebRequest(applicationContext)
}
```

You will need spring test in your build.gradle

```
  compile 'org.springframework:spring-test:2.5'
```

There is a grails 2 branch so follow the same class in the other branch if it is grails 2

Comment: This still works with ServiceUnitTest in Grails 5, I was able to use the session when unit testing a service, at least with `WebUtils.retrieveGrailsWebRequest().session`.