# How create a thread inside an action in Grails

Tags: multithreading, grails, groovy

I am developing a grails application and after the user click on a button the action collector is called. Inside this action I want start a new thread that executes a processing concurrently at the same time that actual thread/action. When I try to do that, I get an error described below. How can I start a thread inside this action?

```
def collector(){
    try{

        println "task1 - starting"
        new Thread( {
            console() //calling another method
        }).start()
        println "task3 - starting"
  ...
}
```

> No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request

Comment: It seems like you are doing something that needs app context from the annoymous thread you created but I would just using ThreadPoolExecutor instead.

Comment: I would move any such logic to a service class.

Comment: As per above comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250539/grails-no-thread-bound-request-found/43260118#43260118. Basically you are attempting to use something within thread that requires current request and because it is set to run outside of current request this issue is happening. If for example you are preparing some gsp stuff in the thread maybe do it centrally before hitting thread and call it from within the thread

Comment: Thanks, @Vahid. After reading the link, I got how to do that.