# createLink in ApplicationTagLib from service

Tags: grails

I am trying to learn about creating the link using createLink from ApplicationTagLib called from the service.

**Grails :** 3.2.8

**Code :**

```
def applicationTag = new ApplicationTagLib()

def abc = application.Tag.createLink(controller:"accomodate", action:"menu", id:4)
```

**Error :**

> org.grails.taglib.GrailsTagException: Tag [createLink] does not exist.
>   No corresponding tag library found.

I am very new to this version. I will be really thankful if you help me in finding out what sort of mistake is my code having.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this:

```
import grails.core.support.GrailsApplicationAware
import grails.core.GrailsApplication
import grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator
   class MyService implements GrailsApplicationAware{
      GrailsApplication grailsApplication
      def config
      LinkGenerator grailsLinkGenerator

      def myMethod() {

          def url = hostname+grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller: 'someController', action: 'something', params:[token:something], absolute: 'false')
    }
     void setGrailsApplication(GrailsApplication ga) {
        config = ga.config
    }
}
```

...

```
String hostname=grailsApplication.config.myApp?.hostName
        def url=hostname+grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller: 'someController', action: 'something', params:[token:something], absolute: 'false')
```

or

```
def url=grailsLinkGenerator.link(controller: 'someController', action: 'something', params:[token:something], absolute: true)
```

**ED2A**
If you must

I have applicationTag lib working this way:

```
import grails.util.Holders
import org.grails.plugins.web.taglib.ApplicationTagLib

 class SomeService { 

 def g = Holders.grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean(ApplicationTagLib)


   def someMethod() {
       def aa = g.createLink('something')
   }
  }
```

The problem with doing things this way is if you start hitting presentation layer references then you may get `No thread-bound request found`. Specially from quartz jobs and anything that is called outside of the scope of a real user. You can get around all of this using [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250539/grails-no-thread-bound-request-found/43260118#43260118). But why go through all that when the grailsLinkGenerator example above won't hit any of the issues that may arise otherwise

Comment: Hi Vahid, Thanks a lot for your reply. I tried with LinkGenerator and ended up with the same error. the grailsLinkGenerator is null and hence the createLink could not be implemented.

Comment: maybe you haven't got right imports. Currently have something like above in a service on a 3.2.8 app myself

Comment: Is there a way to implement createLink from the service?

Comment: Hi Vahid, Thanks a lot. LinkGenerator is working fine . I will try the createLink as I wanna know hows its implemented . Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I came here because I just wanted a link created in a regular **service** class, and [V H's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43663328/12322350)^ helped me; **thank you! :D**

But for those looking for the same thing I was, this is what is sufficient for us to work (Grails version 4.0.4):

```
import grails.web.mapping.LinkGenerator
```

and in the service method:

```
def link = grailsLinkGenerator.link(
  controller: 'controlerName',
  action: 'actionName',
  params: [uuid: "uuidExample"]
)
```

Thank you once more, V H! :)

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can extend your controller with `ResponseRedirector` trait (which explicitly extends your controllers anyway). It'll have `getGrailsLinkGenerator` method. And `LinkGenerator` will have `link` method