# Grails No thread-bound request found when accessing request/session from thread

Tags: multithreading, session, grails

I'm working with Grails 2.5.6.

I have a list of tasks that previously were executed in series and needed to reference a "lang" attribute I have on the session.

Now from the controller I call a class that creates threads, one per each tasks to accelerate the execution. After I added the threads, this error started to appear when the code tries to access the session:

```
No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the o
riginally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outs
ide of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
```

I believe there is something that needs to be setup in the threads I create to be able to access the request/session, but couldn't find any documentation.

The way the session is accessed is:

```
RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().session.lang
```

This worked OK before adding the threads.

Any ideas of what I need to do for that line of code to work on a new thread?

BTW I tried two ways of creating the threads, the classic Thread.start / treads*.join() and using grails.async.Promises (http://docs.grails.org/2.5.6/guide/async.html). On both I get the same error message.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43250539/grails-no-thread-bound-request-found but as per below probably need to clone the params or properties.collect{it} so u capture it as a new list and try to store elements as they are in a new flat map before sending it through this process - it sounds like speedy or lazier ways can sometimes bite - if only session.lang why not grab that and make it map.something=params.lang or session.lang is all i mean

Answer (score 0):

I am also gone through the same issue while  the **params** object passing to the thread run() method from controller, 
The  objects like, params, request and response don't have the longer reference when we pass them to thread, so we need to save that in another variable , what I did as follows,

```
def  paramsData = params // you can declare other objects like request and eesponse
```

Now you can pass variable **paramsData** to your thread.

You can try add requestContext listener in your web.xml and reset app as follows,

```
<web-app> .... <listener> <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class> </listener> <listener> <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener </listener-class> </listener> .... </web-app>
```

Comment: The issue is the class that uses the request is not directly in the thread, but is used be a class, that is used by a class that is invoked form the thread. The only option I see is changing all the methods to pass the session, a solution that I really don't like. IMO there should be some way to actually bind the request to a thread, but it is not documented in the Grails docs and can't find it in the Spring docs.

Comment: Did you try adding requestContext Lister in web.xml?

Comment: I also tried many solutions but nothing was worked  for me , finally I did the above approach which realy worked like charm for me! The issue is we need to expose the scope of request object outsiders like Thread class,.

Comment: I did not, do you have a sample on how that should be done? thanks!

Comment: Just get whatever data you are passing to the thread in one variable which can be of type Map or simply def in your controller or class as I explained in my answer and pass that new variable to thread, which will have the scope to use in thread.

Comment: My question was about adding requestContext Lister in web.xml

Comment: Sorry, it not formated well as I am updating this from mobile